# Access VSFTPD, Ubuntu 12.04 from anywhere

Tags: networking, ftp, ip, vsftpd

I have vsftpd set up at my home PC. I use a airtel broadband connection with a router, hence I have a public IP address and then a private IP address, none of which is static. Locally I can access my FTP through my private IP address, I wanted to know how would I access my computer though a remote location. I'm pretty sure
`ftp://xx.xx.x.xx` // my public IP wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go into your router settings and give your PC a static local IP address.  Then tell your router that every incoming request for ftp (usually port 21) is to be directed to that local IP address.

Specific instructions would be hard because every router is different and they all have a habit of changing their gui every chance they get.

Really surprised no one's answered this yet.  Rocket science it's not.

Comment: Thank you! :) I now have something to work towards :)

Comment: Addendum: this is called Port-Forwarding